# Cannot get OAuth 1.0 Token in OpenBankProject request due to missing oauth_callback

Tags: post, oauth, callback, authorization, postman

I'm trying to use [OpenBankProject](https://github.com/OpenBankProject/OBP-API/wiki/OAuth-1.0-Server#introduction) to get Token, but in Postman I cannot do this due to `Status 400 Bad Request` and `the following parameters are missing : oauth_callback`.

From `doc` I get info that it should be:

- Method POST
- Authorization: Add params to header
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Signature Method: HMAC-SHA256
- Generated Consumer Key and Consumer Secret

And I tried to add Value `oauth_callback="___"` to Key `Authorization` and it returned same error as mentioned above.

Any idea to add `oauth_callback` to this request?

Best regards

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?